# Not getting horizontal space after each record in crystal reports 13.0

Tags: crystal-reports

We were using Visual Studio 2008 and Crystal Reports 10.5. We are displaying a list using crystal report viewer. We are getting some space after every record.

[image: This is image in VS 2008 and CR 10.5]

Now we are upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and Crystal Reports 13.0. We are not getting space after each record. How to get space after each record in CR 13.0 like in CR 10.5

[image: This is image in VS 2015 and CR 13.0]

Comment: May you post a screenshot of your design?

Comment: Very easy.. just open report and drag the section with your fields below. This will add empty space between each record.

Comment: send a screenshot of your report designed

Comment: Dragged fields to the bottom of the section. It gives space between each record but the number of pages  increased @aMazing

Comment: Thats bound to happen. increasing whitespace, will push records down.